# How to find current xml loaded in product page

Tags: magento2, template, xml

I understand the magento 2 template engine but I have difficulties in find the current xml loaded in the product page.

I have searched in the template folder for `catalog_product_view.xml`, I have found one but if I modify it, doesn't works.

Comment: are you using any theme ?

Comment: The template is EREN